# Refresh page after alert box using AJAX in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm doing a form validation in my php script, take one column as an example, if the username is not filled, an alert window will pop up and say "please enter your username", after user click "ok", the whole page refresh but the information on the form will be reset too.

So I would like to keep what the user has input after refreshing the page, how can I embed the code in php using AJAX?

```
        //username validation            
        if (empty($username)) {
        $error = true;
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please enter your username")';
        echo '</script>';
        //refresh the page
        header("Refresh:0; url=register.php");
```

the website is in php file, html code is embedded under the php stuff, and this is the form in the html

```
                <div id="account">
                 <form method="POST">
                    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
                    Username: 
                    <input type="text" name="Username">
                    <span class="error">* </span><br>
                    <!--other fields..-->
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="signup_button">   
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['signup_button'])){
  $Username = $_POST['Username'];
}
?>
```

or...

```
if (empty($username)) {
$error = true;
echo '<script language="javascript">';

/* save the value in the browser */
echo 'window.'+VarYouWantToKeep = $_POST['VarYouWantToKeep'];

echo 'alert("Please enter your username")';
echo '</script>';
//refresh the page
header("Refresh:0; url=register.php");
```

( or use localStorage, instead of window. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage )

Then, when the page loads, check if('window.'+VarYouWantToKeep)

and if it's there, set it as the value="" of the corresponding form field

Comment: so something like `echo 'window.'+$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];` if I want to keep the firstname?

Comment: yes, then when the page loads (document.ready) you would check for 'window.'+firstname and then load that value where you like:   if( window.firstname ) { document.getElementById("id_of_input_field").value = window.firstname; }

Comment: You can do other neat stuff with the window object ( window.location is one of my favourites )  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: should I create a if-statement `if('window.'+ $firstname){$firstname = "";}`after `header("Refresh:0; url=register.php");`?

Comment: Use something like this:   window.onload = doThis; function doThis(){ /* put your if statement here */ }

Comment: should I put the `window.onload `on the top of the code?

Comment: thanks for the help, but I am a bit confuse on how should I modify my current code

Comment: yes, window.onload can go pretty much wherever. javascript is functional, not procedural it executes all at the same time, instead of top to bottom. Anywhere inside a script tag should be fine. And you don't have to do it all at once, try starting with an onload function that does alert('hello');

Comment: so if I implement `window.onload`, I won't need `header("Refresh:0; url=register.php");` anymore?

Comment: submitting the form would take care of refreshing the page, so long as the action attribute is the same file, so I'd say Yes.

Comment: I try to combine all the thing, can you help me to take a look at it? https://jsfiddle.net/ceusr0zt/   thanks!

Comment: here: echo 'window.'+VarYouWantToKeep = $_POST['VarYouWantToKeep']; remember string concat in php is . not +

Comment: so you mean using `echo window.$username = $_POST['username'];` instead?

Comment: `echo "window." . VarYouWantToKeep . " = $_POST['VarYouWantToKeep']; "`

Comment: `echo 'window.'.$username = $_POST['username'];` like this? `if('window.'+ $firstname)` but this don't need to change right?

Comment: That looks alright. JS connect pieces of a string with a +, PHP connect pieces of a string with a .

Answer (score 0):

try this  (This is taking into account you set $username to $_POST["Username"];)

```
 <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["signup_button"]) && $_POST["signup_button"]=="Submit") {echo $username; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

To store variable data, you will need to use `$_SESSION` variables in PHP. Make sure that `session_start()` is at the top of the PHP page.

Here's a basic example:

```
//this PHP page contains the HTML form
<form>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" />
</form>

//ajax
$.ajax({
  url:'validate.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{name:inputName}
 }).done(function(data){
  alert(data);
});

//php page
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
  //set session variable
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  //this will be sent back to PHP page with HTML
  echo 'Please enter username';
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't understand the code flow, why `email` is used for the `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Because you said that you wanted to keep the rest of the user's data. In this example, the user inputted his email but forgot to enter his username.

Comment: How about if user enter an invalid username, and I want to keep all the information (e.g. the username, email...etc.)?

Comment: @纓楓葵 just save all of the form variables as session variables

Answer (score 0):

I coded here, a super cool login page with bootstrap as you expect. Link bootstarp cdn in your html file. This will show the error under the button instead of showing a windows classic alert box. I included ajax request and php response also with some validation.

**login.html**

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="col-lg-offset-8 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4 login-bg">

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#" method="">  
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="User Name" required tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">                        
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" required tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">                        
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-block" type="submit" id="login">Login</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <button class="btn btn-success-outline btn-block" type="reset">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div id="login-feedback" class="btn-block"></div>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**myStyle.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#login').click(function()
            {
                var uname=$('#username').val();             
                var pword=$('#password').val();

                if(uname!='' && pword!='')              
                {
                    $('#login-feedback').text('validating....');
                    $.post("login-check.php",{username:uname,password:pword},function(data)
                    {       
                        if(data=="success")
                        {   

                            $('#login-feedback').fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                            {
                                $(this).html(data).css('color','green').fadeTo(1000,1,function()
                                {
                                    document.location='index.php';
                                });
                            });                     
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#login-feedback').fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
                            {
                                 $(this).html(data).css('color','red').fadeTo(900,1);
                                 //reset form
                                 $('#login').trigger("reset");
                            });
                        }

                    });
                return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#login-feedback').text("Please enter all fields").css('color','purple');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**login-check.php**

```
<?php

   //include connextion file;
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $username=trim($_POST['username']);
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,md5($password));

    if(($username) && ($password))
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($rows>= 1) 
        {
            $fetch_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            session_regenerate_id(true);

            $_SESSION['username']=$fetch_result['username']; 
            $_SESSION['status']=$fetch_result['status'];
            // Close session variable assigns
            session_write_close();
            echo "success";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'Login failed';
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: @AlexHowansky It is a small sample program. We must use password_hash()